# add trigger to every table in my H2 database

Tags: mysql, database, h2

im trying to add a trigger to every database table in my h2 database but im not sure how to do it.

I can select all the tables in the database but how do i loop through them to apply a trigger to each of them like below?

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

and loop through each one and apply a trigger to each

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER AFTER INSERT ON TableName FOR EACH ROW      CALL\"test.h2Trigger\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try create a stored procedure,in which you open a cursor to get each table name, and use server side prepared statement to create the trigger on each table. See http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,27979,30437 for how to use prepared statement.

It can be easier if you use a Perl or php script to do it.

Why do you need create trigger on every table?

Comment: i want to log activity on tables in my database so need to add triggers to each table... Its a h2 database so i dont think it allows stored procedures?

Comment: even they are allowed, they are still expensive.

Comment: yeah i know, but this is purely a local environment thing, not in production

Comment: h2 supports some kind of triggers. Check http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#triggers.

Comment: i have the triggers working if i apply them to a single table, the issue im facing is coming up with a way to apply to all tables on my DB... something like, select ALL table and for each apply trigger