# Add columns to all tables in H2 database without manually listing tables

Tags: sql, h2

I have a PostgreSQL database with about 70 tables and I want to add two columns to each of them, `created_by` and `updated_by`. Since we're using Liquibase, I have written an update script that works fine in PostgreSQL:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  tables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tablename
    FROM pg_tables
    WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'
    ORDER BY tablename;
BEGIN
  FOR table_record IN tables LOOP
    EXECUTE
      'ALTER TABLE ' || table_record.tablename || ' ADD COLUMN created_by BIGINT; ' ||
      'ALTER TABLE ' || table_record.tablename || ' ADD COLUMN updated_by BIGINT;';
  END LOOP;
END$$;
```

However, for integration testing we are using an H2 in-memory database, which doesn't accept this SQL, even in PostgreSQL compatibility mode. [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287369/add-trigger-to-every-table-in-my-h2-database), I know how to select all tables:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

but does this work for `myschema` as well? And is there a way to store the results and loop over them to add the columns? I also don't understand how to use or write prepared statements, as mentioned in the answer.

The basic question is: How can I write an equivalent update script for the H2 database without having to manually list all tables?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do this with H2 syntax. Instead, I used SQL to create the appropriate queries using PostgreSQL syntax:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || tablename || ' ADD COLUMN created_by BIGINT; ' || 
       'ALTER TABLE ' || tablename || ' ADD COLUMN updated_by BIGINT;'
        FROM pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'
        ORDER BY tablename;
```

This returns a list of `ALTER TABLE` queries for all tables, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE first_table ADD COLUMN created_by BIGINT;
ALTER TABLE first_table ADD COLUMN updated_by BIGINT;
```

This does not work dynamically for a changing set of tables, but I only need to execute this for a fixed set of tables, so it works fine for my case.

(I executed the query in SQL Workbench, connected to my PostgreSQL database. The result view lists the queries that were created and they can then be copied to the script file that is executed during testing.)

Answer (score -2):

try something like this :-)

```
DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(20),
    @Table  VARCHAR(50),
    @Query  VARCHAR(4000),
    @Column VARCHAR(100) = 'Column',
    @Column_props VARCHAR(1000) = 'INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'
DECLARE c_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE             
TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
OPEN c_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM c_cursor INTO @Schema, @Table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @Query = '
    IF COL_LENGTH('''+@Schema+'.'+@Table+''', '''+@Column+''') IS NULL  BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE '+@Schema+'.'+@Table+'
      ADD ['+@Column+'] '+@Column_props+'
    END'
    EXEC(@Query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_cursor INTO @Schema, @Table
END
CLOSE c_cursor
DEALLOCATE c_cursor
```

Comment: I dont have puch experience with Postgre.. This would be my solution on MSSQL

Comment: I need it for H2, actually. Executing this gives me `Syntax error in SQL statement: "..." expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX";`

Comment: I had missing 'fetch next' in while loop.. Its edited now. But i think this is not your problem.. sry, dont know much about h2 db system